# how to Iterate JsonArray using java 8

Tags: java, arrays, json, iterator

I have Json array as below

```
{ "template": { "data": [{ "name": "customerGroupId", "value": "" }, { "name": "assetIntegrationId", "value": "" }, { "name": "problemCategory", "value": "" }, { "name": "problemSubCategory", "value": "" }, { "name": "resolutionCode", "value": "" }, { "name": "resolutionSubCode", "value": "" }, { "name": "imei", "value": "" }, { "name": "make", "value": "" }, { "name": "model", "value": "" }] } }
```

I am using following code to get values.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("template").getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObjectData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if ("customerGroupId".equals(jsonObjectData.get("name"))) {
                customerBean.setCustomerGroupId(jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
                LOGGER.debug("JSON customerGroupId  " + jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
            } else if ("assetIntegrationId".equals(jsonObjectData.get("name"))) {
                customerBean.setAssetIntegrationId(jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
                LOGGER.debug("JSON assetIntegrationId  " + jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
            } else if ("problemCategory".equals(jsonObjectData.get("name"))) {
                customerBean.setProblemCategory(jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
                LOGGER.debug("JSON problemCategory  " + jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
            } else if ("problemSubCategory".equals(jsonObjectData.get("name"))) {
                customerBean.setProblemSubCategory(jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
                LOGGER.debug("JSON problemSubCategory  " + jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
            } else if ("resolutionCode".equals(jsonObjectData.get("name"))) {
                customerBean.setResolutionCode(jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
                LOGGER.debug("JSON resolutionCode  " + jsonObjectData.get(VALUE).toString());
            }
```

As the code has become repetitive,Is there any way in Java 8 or Java to avoid repetition of code.

Comment: you can use switch statement

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here , please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854505/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonarray-in-java-8

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure there's an alternative. This is the consequence of your data structure.

Comment: Why do you need to have `name` and `value` keys? It seems to me that they are redundant. You could have for instance `"customerGroupId" : ""` etc. In this way you can do direct assignement to the correct property since you know which property you will be getting from the json.

Comment: Had that to in mind but can't help with the backend Json

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use introspector or reflection.
And use name to find property or field.
Introspector:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
for (int i = json.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(i);
    PropertyDescriptor propDesc = new PropertyDescriptor(data.getString("name"), CustomerBean.class);
    Method methodWriter = propDesc.getWriteMethod();
    methodWriter.invoke(customerBean, data.getString("value"));
}
```

Reflection:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
for (int i = json.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(i);
    Field field = CustomerBean.class.getDeclaredField(data.getString("name"));
    field.set(customerBean, data.get("data"));

}
```

Comment: This problem is not related to the code itself but with the data structure so introspection or reflection won't help.

Comment: Why can't refletion be used? His requirement is that the name in the original array corresponds to the properties in the Java bean, and that data is the value of the properties . He doesn't want so much duplicate code, so is it wrong to use reflection or introspection instead of if?

Comment: You're right. It's a good solution. I wasn't thinking about this.