# Cannot resolve method spliterator JSONArray java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use streams on a JSONArray (imported from org.json.JSONArray) (following another stackoverflow thread here: [How to iterate over a jsonarray in java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854505/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonarray-in-java-8).
However, my IDE (intellij) complains that it cannot resolve the method spliterator.
What am I missing? I can't find any solution online.
Below is the code:

```
private static Stream<Object> arrayToStream(JSONArray array) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(array.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Below in the screenshot, you can see the error the IDE is showing me:
[image]

Comment: show your code and the error message your receiving to better illustrate your description.

Comment: please paste the actual code instead of screenshots as it makes it easier for people to copy and paste your code when attempting to replicate the problem.

Comment: Have you set the IDE java settings to Java 8?

Comment: @theincrediblethor yes, I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the correct dependencies?

Here you are the dependency from Maven repository which work fine!

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20190722</version>
       </dependency>
```

With gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
```

Or you can download it from here:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20190722/json-20190722.jar

Comment: Just a note to say if you are also using spring-boot-starter-test in your dependencies it will pull in a package com.vaadin.external.google:android-json which uses the same package names and class names as the org.json code and doesn't have the splititerator method which confused me for hours until I found and excluded it.